# An extreme multidimension Oracle Group By Select

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

A conundrum I can't figure out

Giving these data in an Oracle table (named tbs_test). First row are column names

```
A  |B| C
100|6|1000
100|6|1001
100|6|1002
100|7|1003 **
200|6|2000
200|6|2001
300|7|3000
300|7|3001
400|6|4000 **
400|7|4001
400|7|4002
```

Through an Oracle SQL select I want to retrieve the two records marked with **.

The rules are:

1. I'm interested in A=100 and A=400 because there are two different B's in the same A

   A=100 has B=6 and B=7

   A=400 has B=6 and B=7
2. I'm interested in C=1003 because there are fewer B=7 (one) than B=6 (three) in A=100

   And I'm interested in C0 4000 because there are fewer B=6 (one) than B=7 (two) in A=100

Man, I'm troubled... Can anyone see the solution?

cheers
Torsten

Comment: if you explain the general goal is better ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation and analytic functions:

```
select a, b, c
from (select a, b, max(c) as c,
             row_number() over (partition by a order by count(*)) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by a) as numBs
      from tbs_test  t
      group by a, b
     ) ab
where seqnum = 1 and numBs > 1;
```

One issue is that this returns only one row for each "A".  It is unclear what to do when there is more than one match on the `B` with the fewest matches.

If you want all `C` values, the simplest way is to use `listagg(C, ',') within group (order by C)` instead of `max(C)`.

Comment: Very elegant. For a analyst-newbie your suggestion for a select-construction seems the most intuitive. Thanks to Gordon Linoff, FyzzyTree and MT0

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from (
    select *, 
        rank() over (partition by a order by cnt) rn
    from (
        select * , 
            count(*) over (partition by a,b) cnt
        from mytable t1
        where exists (
            select 1 from mytable t2
            where t2.a = t1.a
            and t2.b <> t1.b
        )
    ) t
) t where rn = 1
```

- `where exists ...` retrieves rows with more than 1 distinct `B` value
  per `A` group
- `count(*) over ...` counts the # of rows per `(a,b)` pair
- `rank() ...` ranks the rows by the count()
- `where rn = 1` selects the rows with the fewest count

Comment: It almost worked :-) I had to make a minor adjustment: Prefixed the two "*" with the table-alias ("t" and "t1"). Without these aliases Oracle claims that the statement is missing a "from". Strange :-)  <br> ´select * from (
    select t.*, 
        rank() over (partition by a order by cnt) rn
    from (
        select t1.* , 
            count(*) over (partition by a,b) cnt
        from tbs_test t1
        where exists (
            select 1 from tbs_test t2
            where t2.a = t1.a
            and t2.b <> t1.b
        )
    ) t
) t where rn = 1;´

Answer (score 2):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbs_test (A, B, C )AS
SELECT 100,6,1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100,6,1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100,6,1002 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100,7,1003 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200,6,2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200,6,2001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 300,7,3000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 300,7,3001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 400,6,4000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 400,7,4001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 400,7,4002 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT A,B,C
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT( CASE B WHEN 6 THEN 1 END ) OVER ( PARTITION BY A ) AS count6,
         COUNT( CASE B WHEN 7 THEN 1 END ) OVER ( PARTITION BY A ) AS count7
  FROM   tbs_test t
)
WHERE ( B = 6 AND count6 < count7 )
OR    ( B = 7 AND count7 < count6 );
```

**Output**:

```
         A          B          C
---------- ---------- ----------
       100          7       1003 
       400          6       4000
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. To understand count-over-partition, You kan follow this link. Helped me a lot: http://orafaq.com/node/55

Answer (score 0):

I extend the task. In addition to locate the "wrong" B, I want to retrieve the right B-value for an A-group
`select a, b, c, n+p as the_other
from (select a, b, max(c) as c,
             row_number() over (partition by a order by count(*)) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by a) as numbs
             ,lead(b, 1, 0) over (partition by a order by b desc nulls last) as n
             ,lag(b, 1, 0) over (partition by a order by b desc nulls last) as p
      from tbs_test  t
      group by a, b
      ) ab
where seqnum = 1 and numbs > 1;`

Lead and lag does the trick. Man, I'm glad you introduced me to Oracle Analytics